# What does（棒） as net slang mean?

Tags: internet-slang

I was reading a novel at Syosetsuka ni Narou's site and I found（棒） in one of the dialogues. I know that there's a similar（笑） that's equivalent to English net slang "lol", but I find no sense in changing "smile" for "pole". What would it mean?

The chapter in question:
http://ncode.syosetu.com/n2872bw/83/

Comment: It means 棒読み like Espen said. http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E6%A3%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF　← info on where 棒読み came from (why it's "pole") if you care. And more info on how it's used.

Comment: Thanks for the link and thank you and Espen for the info.

Comment: What is the reading of 笑 when used as lol?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a shortening of 棒読み and means speaking in monotone. I.e. if it is an apology or compliment then it is not sincere.